# Tic Tac Toe line cross in front panel LabVIEW

Tags: vi, labview

I need to implement a line strike after if a player wins the game. I've gone through the forum and documentation but it's becoming complex.

Gone through message number 3 and the solution given in [LabVIEW Forum response](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Programmatically-Draw-Line/td-p/404256?profile.language=en).

TODO: After a player won the game, need to strike the sequence. For example: in 3x3 tic tac toe. Player with identity "o" won by having "o" in column 1 - [0,0], [1,0], [2,0] [Row, Column]. Then column 1 should get stricken by decoration line.

Any piece of advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is your main game grid is implemented? Do you use array of controls, or what exactly?

Comment: yes, using an array of buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky question in LabVIEW, since you cannot create a decoration dynamically. However, it is possible to hide it and display dynamically. You can then position and resize it with the use of property nodes. Here is sample code for inspiration:
[image]

Comment: Finding the index of decoration element is a bit difficult and finding position coordinates is also difficult. Anyway, I just guessed it. I accepted it as a solution because it works perfectly as you said. Thanks and I appreciate it. Kudos! :) @Kerghan

Comment: Interesting solution. I thought about creating of picture rings with "x", "o", and then crossed (diagonal, vertical and horizontal) "x" and "o" (so totally 10 pictures) - so then it could be possible to build the crossed line by switching to proper images. But your solution allows to implement desired feature easier :)

Comment: @Kerghan I have a challenging situation now. Without using IMAQ module I have to implement a hand gesture recognition system in LabVIEW, I am trying to find resources. If you have any relevant links please share. Would appreciate your assistance greatly. Thanks in advance. Image inputs using file path control.

Comment: @Pavithran R to be honest, I am not an expert in this area. However, if you cannot for some reason use in-build machine vision in LabVIEW as you mentioned, the best way I can see is to build your own neural network to recognize hand gestures - or even better, find an open source one on github. However, such a task might be extremely time consuming. You might use labview python nodes and use some python framework such as tensorflow. But as said, this would take very long time and as long as you are not proficient in machine learning it might be not worth the effort.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Thanks, much @Kerghan I'll try and update the post.